# angular-translation and user depending language select

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

i have installed the angular-translation.

at the app.js i set

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: '/app/languages/',
    suffix: '.json'
}).registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['de_DE','en_US'], {
    'en_US': 'en_US',
    'en_UK': 'en_US',
    'en': 'en_US',
    'de': 'de_DE'
}).fallbackLanguage('en_US').useLocalStorage();
```

at the loginCtrl i set the user language

```
angular.module('app').controller('mySigninCtrl',function($scope, $http, $log, myIdentity, myNotifier, myAuth, $location, $translate, $routeParams) {
$scope.signin = function(username, password) {
        myAuth.authenticateUser(username, password).then(function(success){
            if(success) {
                angular.element('body').addClass("skin-blue");
                $translate.refresh();
                $translate.use(myIdentity.currentUser.language).then(function() {
                    $translate('account.signin.notifier.successfull').then(function (text) {
                        myNotifier.notify(text);
                    });
                    $location.path('/dashboard');

                });
            } else {
                $translate('account.signin.notifier.error').then(function (text) {
                    myNotifier.notify(text);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

but at the dashboard i can't get the translations in de_DE for example...